# Using Linq to Determine if List of Uris is Base of another Uri

Tags: linq

I would like to build a method that determines if a given URL is a child of one of a number of URL's in a List.  I  thought of approaching this using Linq but the syntax seems beyond my understanding.  Here is what I have attempted and I would expect isChild == true.

```
List<Uri> ProductionUriList = new List<Uri>(){
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/Engineering",UriKind.Absolute),
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/APAC",UriKind.Absolute),
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/China",UriKind.Absolute),
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/EMEA",UriKind.Absolute),
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/India",UriKind.Absolute),
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/Mexico",UriKind.Absolute),
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/SamCam",UriKind.Absolute),
    new Uri(@"https://my.contoso.com/sites/USA",UriKind.Absolute),
};


var isChild = 
        ProductionUriList.SelectMany (p => p.IsBaseOf(new Uri("https://my.contoso.com/sites/China/Site1",UriKind.Absolute)));
```

The runtime error says:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check for a bool condition on a set you can use the any operator:

```
    var isChild = ProductionUriList.Any(p => p.IsBaseOf(new Uri("https://my.contoso.com/sites/China/Site1", UriKind.Absolute)));
```

Concerning your error: The selectmany operator expects a delegate that returns IEnumerable which you do not supply. You are mixing up select and selectmany. If you choose select as the linq operator you could do a count > 0 on the result which would give the same result as using the any operator:

```
var isChild = ProductionUriList.Select(p => p.IsBaseOf(new Uri("https://my.contoso.com/sites/China/Site1", UriKind.Absolute)).Count > 0;
```

Comment: The second "answer" is wrong, see my (Henrik Cookes) second answer answer below for a correct counting.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the uri is a child of one or more:

```
var isChild = ProductionUriList.Any(p => p.IsBaseOf(newUri("https://my.contoso.com/sites/China/Site1",UriKind.Absolute)));
```

To determine if the uri is a child of exactly one:

```
var isChild = ProductionUriList.Count(p => p.IsBaseOf(newUri("https://my.contoso.com/sites/China/Site1",UriKind.Absolute))) == 1;
```